# Input text field GUI

Tags: gui-construction, text, inputfield

Is there a way to input multiple rows of text and save it as a variable? Like an InputField, but with multiple rows? I would like to make a simple text redactor, so that I could enter a text and then use it as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `InputField` will work. You just need to use `\[NewLine]` when you need it. Create a pallete for this purpose or a shortkey, or event handler.

You can use a quick fix too:

```
InputField[
           Dynamic[x, (x = StringReplace[#, "\\n" -> "\n"]) &],
           String, ContinuousAction -> True]
```

[image]

so now every time you type "\n" it will create new line.

Is this what you're after?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have smth more user-friendly since my future application will be used by people without Mathematica experience, but this will work, thx.

Comment: @Wenli Take a look at my comment under your question

Comment: Thx! That's a duplicate indeed.